# HTMLEditorFor with dropdown list in C# Form

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4, C# and would like to add a dropdown selection list of three items to an HTMLEditorFor statement. I have looked and cannot find a coding example specific to what I have or close enough to follow. Here is the code I want to modify:

(this is within an Html form and is a form group level item)

```
<div class="form group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChoreStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { class="form-control" }})    
       @Html.ValidationMessage(..)
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add coding for a list box of three Chore Status selections: "Not Started", "In Process" and "Complete!". My suspicion is the code will replace the "form-control" part of the class. I could pass the values from the controller via the ViewBag. I have tried to formulate using SelectListItem in a variety of ways. Can anyone point me to a relevant example it would be so greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: In the controller - `ViewBag.ChoreStatusList = new SelectList(.....);` and in the view `@Html.DropDowmListFor(m => m.ChoreStatus, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ChoreStatusList, new { class="form-control" })` (although its better to pass the `SelectList` to the view as a view model property

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  Just saw this. This is the part I was having the most trouble with. I'll get right on it! (PS: "Down" is misspelled and the parameter for class needs the "@". Still, hoping to be much closer!

Comment: OK, in the view where I am using the @Html.DropDownFor, I got this error code: Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ChoreStatus'.

Comment: and - I am trying to pass a list - does this require 2 arguments ( text, value) or will the 'DropDownListFor'  handle the binding with just a simple list?

Comment: The error means that that `ChoreStatus` is not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. I suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future. I was able to build a nice shell - soon as the HtmlEditorFor figured out I wanted a drop down it balked. I put a simple drop down into place directly into the Html. Beautiful and got it working in no time. I also didn't want to go through the whole process of building an editor ascx file, etc. as I am now taking this version into Angular where the dropdowns are handled in a different manner - probably easier. I appreciate your assistance - I will do a look-up and refresh on the IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future. I was able to build a nice list, and it did not like the command line. I at least had it where it was accepted by IntelliSense - soon as the HtmlEditorFor figured out I wanted a drop down it balked. I put a simple drop down into place directly in the Html. Beautiful and working in no time. I also didn't want to go through the process of building an editor ascx file, etc. as I am now taking this version into Angular where the dropdowns are handled differently, probably easier. I will look up IEnumerable if needed. I do appreciate your assistance!